# I want to display {00.00} this format in editable control with using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Whatever number is entered, I want `{00.00}` this kind of format when it popup, some how I am not getting that function or logic behind it:

[image]

```
$('#EstimatedHours').editable({
    showbuttons: false,
    unsavedclass: null,
    type: 'text',
    inputclass: 'estimatedhours-select',
    mode: 'popup',
    emptytext: 'Hours',
    clear: false,
    url: function (params) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("OnEstimatedHoursChange", "MyTasks")';
        var taskId = $("#SelectedTaskID").val();
        var EstHours = params.value
        var model = {
            "TaskID": taskId,
            "EstimatedHours": params.value
        }
        debugger;
        $("#dvLoading").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: model
        }).done(function (e) {
            debugger;
            $("#EstimatedHours").text($('.estimatedhours-select').val());
            $("#dvLoading").hide();
            toastr.success('Hours updated successfully.', 'Success', { timeOut: 5000, positionClass: "toast-bottom-right", closeButton: true })
            var taskid = $("#SelectedTaskID").val();
            $("#MainTaskHour-" + taskid).text(EstHours);
            $("#divTaskLatestEvents").html(e);
            
            document.getElementById('EstimatedHours').innerHTML = EstHours;//parseFloat(Math.round(EstHours * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            
            });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example on how you can format the input so it looks like `{00.00}` format you want.

```js
function onInputHandler(event) {
  const
    inputValue = sanatizeInput(event.target.value),
    outputElement = document.getElementById('myOutput');
  
  if (outputElement !== null) {
    outputElement.textContent = formatInputAsTime(inputValue);
  }
}

function sanatizeInput(value) {
  // Return the provided value after replacing everything which
  // isn't a digit with an empty string. The resulting string 
  // will only contain digits.
  return value.replace(/\D/g, '');
}

function formatInputAsTime(value) {
 const
    // Make sure the string is always at least 4 characters long.
    paddedValue = value + '0000',
    // Take the first 4 characters from the string, this will contain
    // the user's input padded with extra zeroes as needed.
    displayValue = paddedValue.substr(0, 4);
    // Take the first 2 chars, add a dot and add the last 2 characters.
    return `${displayValue.substr(0, 2)}.${displayValue.substr(-2)}`;
}

// Get the input element from the DOM and listen to its change event.
const
  inputElement = document.getElementById('myInput');
  
if (inputElement !== null) {
  inputElement.addEventListener('input', onInputHandler);
}

// This will print 10.00
console.log(formatInputAsTime('1'));
// This will print 12.30
console.log(formatInputAsTime('123'));
// This will print 12.34
console.log(formatInputAsTime('12345'));
```

```css
.output {
  color: royalblue;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: .5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter time">
<p>
formatted output:
</p>
<div id="myOutput" class="output"></div>
```

Whatever the user enters in the input is converted to a string with just digits which in turn will be formatted to `00.00`.